# Calling a method of a mock object

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am testing a service with PHPUnit.

I am using `setUp()` to create mock objects of the dependencies that my service accepts, like this:

```
 public function setUp()
    {
        $this->fooManagerMock = $this->getFooManagerMock();
        $this->barManagerMock = $this->getBarManagerMock();
        $this->treeManagerMock = $this->getTreeManagerMock();
        $this->loggerMock = $this->getLoggerMock();

     $this->myService = new MyService($this->fooManagerMock, $this->barManagerMock, $this->treeManagerMock, $this->loggerMock);
    }
```

Bundle\Tests\Service\MyTest::testServiceWithValidData

```
   /**
     * @dataProvider getServiceValidCaseData
     */
    public function testServiceWithValidData($case)
    {
         $this->assertTrue($this->myService->serve($fooArray));
    }
```

It turns out that a entity manager that in my `serve()` function, I am having something like this:

`return $this->fooManager->find($fooId) !== null;`

in this case $this->fooManager is instance of `Mock_FooManager_4038382a` and the whole test fails.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

**UPDATE**

```
/**
     * @return \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockBuilder
     */
    private function getFooManagerMock()
    {
        return $this->getMockBuilder(
            '\MyBundle\Entity\Manager\FooManager'
        )->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    }
```

**Example for @matteo**

I was expecting `$fooManager->find($id)` to return me a specific instance of Foo, such as:

```
\MyBundle\Manager\FooManager{
"id" : 234234,
"status" : "pending".
"color" : "yellow",
"tree" : [
         "id" : 2345,
         "height" :160
       ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code of the `getFooManagerMock ` method?

Comment: It isn't clear from the details provided what your problem is. How does 'and the whole test fails' manifest itself? Does your mock FooManager provide an implementation of find() that returns something sensible when passed $fooId?

Comment: @Matteo I have just updated my initial post.

@redbirdo My FooManager includes a `find($id) method`, which contains this: `return $this->getRepository()->find($id);`
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify in the test case which behaviour the mocked entity must do, try adding this code in the `testServiceWithValidData` method, before call the tested service:

```
       $fooMockObj = $this->getMock('\MyBundle\Entity\Foo');
       // Eventually mock some method
       // PS You can return a concrete instance too
       // $fooMockObj= new  \MyBundle\Entity\Foo();

        $this->fooManager
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('find')
//            ->with($anOptionalInputId)
             ->will($this->returnValue($fooMockObj));
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is something that tried before and works, *but* thing is that from my `find($id)` I am expecting to receive a Foo instance, which is then used.

`$foo = $this->fooManager->find($id);
$foo->getStatus();`

Comment: of course, you can mock a `Foo` class and then return it in the mocked expectation method, instead of the `true` value. Let me know If you need an example code

Comment: you can return a concrete object instance too if  you prefer

Comment: I see what you mean and I am a bit sceptical about it.
The problem is that the expected instance is an enormous object, containing objects and in some cases objects of objects, and mocking it out could take 500 code lines.

Comment: you can mock only the object/method you need

Comment: could you provide me a code example of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @thitami. I already updated my answer with the `$fooMockObj = $this->getMock('\MyBundle\Entity\Foo');` etc... you can mock only the method of the object you need for satisfy the test. Is difficult add more for me without more code or a concrete example.....

Comment: Seems clear, thanks! But what about if I am expecting a specific instance to be returned ?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean, you want a specific instance for assert that the result is the same? Try updating your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80199/discussion-between-thitami-and-matteo).